# How to improve 'Do you learn, remember, and understand more from reading on paper than on screen?'

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I wrote [the question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/26708/16959) so am necessarily biased. Would someone more experienced here and more learned in writing advise on rewriting or perhaps edit it directly, with the goal of having this question reopened?
 My English woefully is too basic.

Answer (score 1):

The article you link already presents a lot of evidence, and some expert opinion. It does not take a very strong position on the matter, besides stating that each media is different.

The other sources you present are simply comments of people debating the article.

There seems to be no specific claim to address: people debating in comments are not notable sources; the article itself doesn't make strong unsubstantiated claims we can address, and already presents the evidence on the matter of reading on different media.

I am not sure there is anything else that can be improved besides focusing the totality of the question on specific claims in the article.